# JavaScript change img src

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make an image slider just using JavaScript. I have a button with an id in HTML and want to change the src of the button based on a position in an array. This is my following code.

```
var index = 0;
var imageArray = [{'images/img1.jpg'},{'images/img2.jpg'},{'images/img3.jpg'},{'images/img4.jpg'}];

function moveToNextSlide()
{
    if (index >= imageArray.length -1)
    {
        index =-1;
    }
    var img = getElementById(img_start);
    index = index + 1;
    var currentSlide = imageArray[index];
    getElementByid(img_start).src="currentSlide";

}
```

Comment: And what does not work?

Comment: Can you add your html please?

Comment: @RossGlover. did the answer I provided below work?

Comment: Many thanks, also cleared some clear fundamental parts of JavaScript I did not understand.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're trying to create an array of strings. You have:

```
var imageArray = [{'images/img1.jpg'},{'images/img2.jpg'},{'images/img3.jpg'},{'images/img4.jpg'}];
```

Braces (`{}`) are used to declare *objects*; the braces you have around each string are a syntax error. For just an array of strings, simply leave the quoted literals without braces:

```
var imageArray = ['images/img1.jpg','images/img2.jpg','images/img3.jpg','images/img4.jpg'];
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues. Firstly, you need to use the correct `array` syntax.

```
var imageArray = ['images/img1.jpg','images/img2.jpg','images/img3.jpg','images/img4.jpg'];
```

Also, you need to use `document.getElementById` and set as `getElementById` on it's own will refer to the `window`, not the `document`.

Finally, you need to set to the variable `currentSlide` like so `img.src= currentSlide;`, not `"currentSlide"` as a string.

```
function moveToNextSlide(){
    if (index >= imageArray.length -1){
        index =-1;
    }
    var img = document.getElementById('img_start');
    index = index + 1;
    var currentSlide = imageArray[index];
    img.src= currentSlide;
}
```

See full example here

```js
var index = 0;
var imageArray = ['http://www.profightdb.com/img/wrestlers/thumbs-600/1414330df8brethart.jpg', 'http://armpit-wrestling.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/bret-hart.jpg'];

document.body.onload = function(){
   document.getElementById('img_start').src = imageArray[0];
};

function moveToNextSlide() {
  if (index >= imageArray.length - 1) {
    index = -1;
  }
  var img = document.getElementById('img_start');
  index = index + 1;
  var currentSlide = imageArray[index];
  img.src = currentSlide;
}
```

```css
img {
  max-width: 100px;
}

p {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<img id="img_start" src="">
<p onclick="moveToNextSlide()">Click Here</p>
```